# I already corrected the "too broad" issue!

Tags: discussion

Question: [What do the nomodeset, quiet and splash kernel parameters mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716957/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-ubuntu-boot-options)

I have added a note to correct the "too broad" issue on my question. However, it was closed anyway (incorrectly) as "too broad", but it is not too broad anymore. Is it still "too broad" or it's incorrectly closed (like i thought)? By the way, the "reopen" has (1) on the front of it beacuse i voted to reopen it.

Comment: You voted to reopen it? The ability to vote to close/reopen is given at 3k, you don't even have 1k yet, how did you vote to reopen it?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I don't know. It appeared there.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, it's been a while since I was bellow 1k so I didn't remember about the fact that you get the ability to cast close/reopen votes on your own questions at 250 rep.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Oh, OK.

Comment: I voted to reopen, but still confused with your note points

Comment: @Ravan Note points? What are note points?

Comment: @Ravan OK, it made the post look much nicer, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must wait a bit for the reopen, it takes 5 votes (from 3k users I think) just like a close vote, you now have 4 reopen votes as of writing this, so just be patient, it will reopen shortly.